# Google Earth Engine error message

Tags: google-earth-engine, error

What does this error mean in Google Earth Engine? Nothing is working for me at the moment. Is it down?

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://content-earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/algorithms?prettyPrint=false&key=AIzaSyCIdO53SBE0yrw3mmxBnfF3HeIIj316gA0'.
```

Answer (score 1):

1 hour and a half ago I received the same message. I can't carry out any process. So, the GEE must be down

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. Hope it comes back soon.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the network. Check your network and try again.